# Удаление одинаковых элементов в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Мне дан массив (который я вбиваю через клавиатуру), нужно избавиться от повторяющиихся элементов. Я написал, но у меня всегда остаётся последней элемент из повторяющихся чисел (пример: `1 1 1 3`, программа выдаёт `1 3`, а должно выдать только `3`). Как избавиться от этого последнего элемента?

Вот сам код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i,n,j;
    int a[100];
    printf("Введите количество элементов\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (a[i]==a[i+1]) {
            for (j=i; j<n; j++) {
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
        n--;
        i--;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);


}
```

Ещё прошу объяснить, как вы дошли до верного решения.

Comment: "программа выдаёт 1 3" Так она это и должно выдавать, нет?

Comment: Наверное она должна выдавать просто 3, но она и при выводе 1 3 удаляет только последовательно повторяющиеся числа. Если исходную последовательность взять 1 1 4 1 3, то будет на выходе 1 4 1 3

Comment: да-да, только 3

Comment: @tilin в том то и проблема, прога не проверяет последний элемент, и не знаю, как сделать чтоб она проверила его и убрала

Comment: @tilin если не сложно помоги, пожалуйста

Comment: Программирование -- это прежде всего *структуры данных*, а уже потом код. Ваш классический случай называется *Set*. То есть перестроением в дерево дубли сразу же исчезают (или их можно подсчитать, или их позиции запомнить, или ...). Скорость операции *O(n)* (с небольшой поправкой на ребалансировку дерева. Второй вариант, сортировка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант. Можно сразу читать в счетчик, но у вас в условии **дан массив**, и я подумал, что использование массива int обязательно.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// стуктура-счетчик
struct av
{
  int value;
  int count;
};

int main()
{
    int i, n, x;
    int a[100];
    struct av counter[100] = {0}; // пустой счетчик

    printf("Введите количество элементов\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
        if (!counter[x].count) // если элемент еще не посчитан, добавим +1
        {
          counter[x].value = a[i];
          counter[x].count++;
          break;
        }
        else if (counter[x].value == a[i]) // если элемент посчитан и value == этому элементу
        {
          counter[x].count++; // увеличим счетчик
          break;
        }
    }
    // просто выведем те элементы, кол-во которых == 1
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
      if (counter[i].count == 1)
        printf("%d\t", counter[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое. У меня вопрос, можно ли обойтись (временно, разумеется) меньшими знаниями (как у меня), не используя struct, value, count (обязательно с ними ознакомлюсь). Короче, можно ли добавить какое-нибудь условие или что-то в этом роде, чтоб всё заработало без дополнительный фитч (покрасней мере для меня это фитчи). 
P.S. крутой рейтинг, но я испорчу)

Comment: Если у вас элементы массива это только положительные целые числа, то можно просто еще один массив `счетчик[элемент]++`, ну и необходимо знать максимальное возможное вводимое целое число или динамически выделять память под счетчик.

Comment: Или второй счетчик для отрицательных целых: `счетчик[элемент_по_модулю]++`

Comment: понял, тогда пошёл читать про новшества, которые вы показали, спасибо!

Comment: @JackWolf тут из нового только `struct`

Comment: ну, да, пойду получать новые знания) Ещё раз большое, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например, так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int uniq(int * a,  // Массив
         int n)    // Количество элементов
{
    int * f = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (f[i]) continue; // Уже проверен
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            if (a[i] == a[j]) { f[i]++; f[j]++; } // Если есть - выставляем флаги...
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (f[i] == 0) a[count++] = a[i];  // Собираем вначале
    free(f);
    return count;  // Количество "уникумов"
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int test[10] = { 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0, 3, 3 };
    int new_count = uniq(test,10);
    for(int i = 0; i < new_count; ++i) printf("%d ",test[i]);
    puts("");
}
```

Т.е. еще один массив, в котором выставляем флаг, если есть дубль. Потом собираем в начало исходного массива только те, у которых дублей нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Скажи, пожалуйста, возможно ли "заставить" работать код, который представил я? Если возможно помоги, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Harry у меня без приведения **int * f = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));** не компилируется

Comment: @tilin видимо, собираете как плюсовый код. В сишном преобразование от `void*` работает неявно.

Comment: @Harry точно, сишный код компилируется. Не знал. Спасибо.

Comment: @JackWolf Ну принцип у вас не тот... его двумя строками не исправить.